# PHP or statement ||

Tags: php

Use of `||` (or)

I got so many values which I need to compare with same variable, is there a better way to write more efficiently such as `$city == -35 || -34 || -33` or even simpler so that I don't have to repeat variable name since it's the same variable only value keep changing.

```
<?php

if ($city == -35 || $city == -34 || $xcity == -33)
{
    $region = "noindex";
}

?>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: For that particular situation, `$city > -36 && $city < -32` :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/function.in-array.php)

```
if (in_array($city, array(-35, -34, -33))) {
  $region = "noindex";
}
```

Or if they are consecutive ( I suspec they aren't and this is just an example)

```
in_array($city, range(-35, -33))
```

Comment: When I tried above code I got this error?

    `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/webzds/public_html/index.php on line 702`

Comment: @Mas It was just missing one `)`. Fixed above.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Use [`in_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php),

```
in_array($city, array(-35,-34,-33))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
if (in_array($city, array(-35, -34, -33))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `$xcity` is a typo,

```
switch ($city)
{
case -35:
case -34:
case -33:
     $region = "noindex";
     break;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this isn't the accepted answer.  While slightly more verbose than the `in_array` suggestions (and I'm not sure about the execution time of the two), but this would be the "right" way to do what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Use associative array. in_array compare each element in array with your var. Associative array used hashtable. It faster.

```
$cities = array(-33 => 1, -34 => 1, -35 => 1);
if (isset($cities[$city])) {
    $region = "noindex";
}
```

Comment: What if `$city` is -36? This method would throw a notice. Best to check with `isset()`